# mi consola tira error cuando quiero usar require js, dice que no esta definido

Tags: javascript, nodejs, requirejs

Este es mi **HTML** linkeado con mis archivos **js**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scrap.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="require.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

este es mi archivo **scrap.js**

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
// tengo problema con el require, la consola me tira error

request('https://www.cotodigital3.com.ar/sitios/cdigi/', (error, response, html) => {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(html);
  }
});
```

mi archivo **require.js** contiene literalmente lo que esta en esta pagina (copie y pegue de https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/minified/require.js )

(no me deja subirlo porque es una gran linea de código)

Comment: Invierte el orden de carga de tus scripts, primero coloca el script de `require.js` y luego pon tu script de `scrap.js`. Comenta el resultado

Comment: Se solucionó, pero ahora me aparecen estos dos errores: `Identifier 'request' has already been declared` ;  `Module name "request" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

Comment: Muy bien, ahora te estás enfrentando a un problema en la forma en que `RequireJS` realiza la carga de módulos. Trataré de darte una respuesta, tan pronto pueda. Saludos